# How to automatically change a specific text value with an input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to achieve is that when I'm entering an input value, the specific number of a textarea's value would replaced too according to the input value.

F.e: If I would enter into the input value a number `4`, textarea's specific value (in this case a number) would be `4` too. If I would delete a value from the input, the value would be deleted from textarea too.

As you can see in the snippet, it works bad. It changes a value just one time. After that, 'text-areas' value isn't changing.

Could someone help me with that? Thank you for your time

```js
    $('.text1').keyup(function() {
        var recommendationText = $('.textarea');
        var specificString = '4';
        var str = $('.textarea').val().replace(specificString, $(this).val());
        
       recommendationText.val(str);
        specificString = $(this).val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="text1">
<textarea rows="4"  class="textarea" cols="50">
This is a textarea of 4 rows.
</textarea>
```

Comment: `It changes a value just one time.` You mean it works once or only replaces one 4 out of multiple?

Comment: @epascarello it only works once. After that, I can change an input, but the textarea's value isn't changing too. (That number 4)

Comment: Oh it is because you change the orginal string... There is no longer a 4 in it...

Comment: Well, your new textarea val doesn't have specific string anymore, right?

Comment: You are searching for '4' LITERALLY. Once it has been changed you won't find it again so it'll change nothing. There is no 4 left to replace.

Comment: It will fail if textbox doesn't have any value

Comment: @HELPME do you maybe need alterable states on textare? so if in text area is number 5 for ex. than that input would cought and update that state?

Comment: I think that OP get scared with so many answers off, where the only thing that was needed was to change `rows="4" ` prop on textarea :) hahaha

Comment: @KresimirPendic I'm a little bit confused now with so many answers, so I wonder which one should I apply

Comment: the one that you need man,, and if it's correct right?

Comment: @KresimirPendic The `rows` html attribute has nothing to do with this question. I don't quite understand why so many people have answered a question that has already been answered several times.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code. The first is that the `specificString` value is being reassigned each time you do a keyup, so you need to set the default outside of the event handler. But also, if you delete the value, it will have no way of finding it and will prepend it to the start.

I'd personally recommend using a template based approach, rather than storing the previous value:

```js
var specificString = '[numRows]';
var recommendationText = $('.textarea').val();
$('.text1').keyup(function() {
  var numRows = $(this).val();
  if (isNaN(parseFloat(numRows)) || !isFinite(numRows) || numRows.length < 1) {
    numRows = 0;
  }
  var str = recommendationText.replace(specificString, numRows);
  $('.textarea').val(str);
}).keyup();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="text1" value="4">
<textarea rows="4"  class="textarea" cols="50">
This is a textarea of [numRows] rows.
</textarea>
```

This could use a proper templating language like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com) or [Underscore.js templates](http://underscorejs.org/), but that is too opinion-based to include in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to modify my answer to show a more template based version, but as it stands it's not possible to support deletion

Comment: Accepts string..!

Comment: But, Initially we need to get the value `(4)` from textarea.

Comment: @RohitSharma What do you mean? The question seems to make out that the input field leads the value of the textarea. So I put the default into the input field instead. But it would hardly be difficult to move where that default value is stored.

Answer (score 0):

In your way your code would work. Just change your code like this..! There are some logical issues in your code. Initiate the value of `specificString` outside the `keyup()` method to get first 4 and then then the value of textbox.

```js
var recommendationText = $('.textarea');
var specificString = recommendationText.val().match(/\d+/);
$('.text1').keyup(function() {
if($(this).val() != '' && $.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
    var str = $('.textarea').val().replace(specificString, $(this).val());
   recommendationText.val(str);
   specificString = $(this).val();
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="text1">
<textarea rows="4"  class="textarea" cols="50">
This is a textarea of 4 rows.
</textarea>
```

Comment: Causes different issues, type in `This`

Comment: @epascarello made validation for numerical value..!

Comment: I still think it's not a great idea to use a hard-coded `specificString` replacement value though

Comment: Okay @MattFletcher..! Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is much easier than you might expect.

**Note:** The $ in ${inputVal} is not jquery, its part of template literals. Don't get confused there.

```js
document.getElementById('text1').onkeyup = changeTextArea;

function changeTextArea() {
  let inputVal = document.getElementById('text1').value;
  let text = `This is a textArea of ${inputVal} rows`;
  document.getElementById("textarea").value = text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="text1">
<textarea rows="4"  id="textarea" cols="50">
This is a textarea of 4 rows.
</textarea>
```

Comment: It is a valid answer in my book if OP is okay with the string being hardcoded in the function.

Comment: It opens a whole new can of worms though with using ES6 syntax and browser compatibility. Also mixed jQuery/vanilla. If using ES6, could even just be a one-liner of `$('.text1').keyup((e)=>$('#textarea').val(\`This is a textarea of ${$(e.target).val()} rows\`));`

Comment: @epascarello OP says nothing about string not being hardcoded. So, I think its OK.

Comment: @MattFletcher End of my day, hence couldnt put the extra effort to make it pure js; also I am aware of crunching my solution to one; but for sake of readability, I made it into 3 lines; Anything wrong with that?

Comment: Oh, I meant keeping it entirely as jQuery, as that's what OP is using, not changing it all to vanilla. And yes I agree that the 3 lines is better, I was just saying that it seemed like your suggestion of using ES6 syntax was for the sake of making it compact.

Comment: @MattFletcher es6 and pure js were personal preferences; thats all. Still dont understand why someone downvoted..

Comment: @RajkumarSomasundaram Sorry, I downvoted it because I felt that the flurry of answers which just recreated the string in JS were making very little effort to actually answer the question as presented... but, on reflection, I think it's probably unfair seeing as OP didn't really specify.

Answer (score 0):

Declare and initialize `specificString` outside of `keyup()` event.Otherwise your value for `specificString` will be always 4.

```
var specificString = '4';

$('.text1').keyup(function() {
        var recommendationText = $('.textarea');
        var str = $('.textarea').val().replace(specificString, $(this).val());            
        recommendationText.val(str);
        specificString = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your issue is you replace the string so next time you look for the 4 it is not there. Reason why is you redefine `specificString` inside of the loop so it is always 4 and not what the user last typed. So if you move it outside it will work ("sort of")

Your design will fail if the user enters in something that matches another word. EG `This`, it will replace the first occurrence, not the string you want to replace. Or if you delete the string, you will not have any match.

So what can you do? I would use a data attribute with the original and use that. And I would make some sort of "template" so you know what you are replacing and do not replace another part of the string with the replacement when user matches text.

```js
$('.text1').keyup(function() {
  var ta = $('.textarea')
  var specificString = /\{4\}/;
  var entry = $(this).val() || "4";
  var str = ta.data("text").replace(specificString, entry);
  ta.val(str);
}).trigger("keyup");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="text1">
<textarea rows="4" class="textarea" cols="50" data-text="This is a textarea of {4} rows.">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Regex seems kinda unnecessary

Comment: It is just a preference. Yes OP can use `var specificString = "{4}"` if they clearly want.

Comment: semicolon after line 2

Comment: @epascarello I got an error which says that replace is undefined.

Comment: I assume you did not change the HTML